# Printing JSON properties

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently trying to send a user information about a JSON object that I've recieved from an API. An example of the format is

```
[
{
    "lang_code":        "eng",
    "site_language":    "1",
    "name":         "English"
},
{
    "lang_code":        "afr",
    "site_language":    "1",
    "name":         "Afrikaans"
},
{
    "lang_code":        "ale",
    "site_language":    "0",
    "name":         "Aleut"
},
]
```

I want to be able to access the `lang_code` property of every single language and send it. I've tried to use

```
var languageCodes;
var languageResult = body.lang_code; //body is the result from a request.get({ ... })
for(var codes in languageResult) {
    languageCodes = languageResult[codes];
}
```

Object.keys does nothing, as it just sends 72 numbers to me. Any thoughts?

On a side note, I also want people to be able to type "**! languages [my command] eng**", for example, and it sends "English" instead of just sending "1 is [object Object]".

Comment: You'll have to explain your *"side note"* more thoroughly, perhaps with some code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming body is the array at the top of your question, if you just want an array of all the language codes, this should suffice

```
var languageCodes = body.map(function(lang) {
    return lang.lang_code;
});
```

```js
var body = [{
  "lang_code": "eng",
  "site_language": "1",
  "name": "English"
}, {
  "lang_code": "afr",
  "site_language": "1",
  "name": "Afrikaans"
}, {
  "lang_code": "ale",
  "site_language": "0",
  "name": "Aleut"
}];

var languageCodes = body.map(function(lang) {
  return lang.lang_code;
});

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(languageCodes);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: @dragonbanshee See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map for more info

Comment: Also any idea about doing the "!languages eng"? I did a .split command, and put the words into an array called "params". So like params[1] would be eng.

Comment: @dragonbanshee I have no idea what that `!languages eng` is meant to mean. What syntax is that?

Comment: Sorry, it means when I send a message to my bot, the message `!languages eng`, it checks if `eng` is a valid language code. If it is, it should say `eng is English`. If it isn't, it should say `eng is not a valid language code`. Is there a way to select individual objects in that JSON array I had in the original post and see if the values match?

Comment: @dragonbanshee I'm still not sure what you mean and I don't know what your "bot" is. You could just check to see if a code is in the array using `languageCodes.indexOf('eng') !== -1`

Answer (score 0):

I looped through your lang_codes like this:

```
var codes = [{"lang_code":"eng","site_language":"1","name":"English"}, {"lang_code":"afr","site_language":"1","name":"Afrikaans"},{"lang_code":"ale","site_language":"0","name":"Aleut"}];

for(var i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
    console.log(codes[i].lang_code);
}
```